# CountIfs in VBA where entries are between two dates

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count number of treatments but this returns 0 for all values.

I am sure that StartDate, EndDate and MachineSerial are correct when my code gets to this point.

```vb
Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("D" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("MachineData").Range("A:A"), MachineSerial, Worksheets("MachineData").Range("D:D"), ">=" & CDate(StartDate), Worksheets("MachineData").Range("D:D"), "<=" & CDate(EndDate) + 0.999988, Worksheets("MachineData").Range("L:L"), ">=1")
```

This is what the COUNTIFS would look like as a formula and this works.

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!A:A,C3,MachineData!D:D,">="&$A$14,MachineData!D:D,"<="&$A$27+0.999988,MachineData!L:L,">=1")
```

This is how I obtain `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

```vb
StartDay = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A6").Value
StartMonth = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A9").Value
StartYear = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A12").Value

StartDate = StartDay & "/" & StartMonth & "/" & StartYear
Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A14").Value = CDate(StartDate)

EndDay = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A19").Value
EndMonth = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A22").Value
EndYear = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A25").Value

EndDate = EndDay & "/" & EndMonth & "/" & EndYear
Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("A27").Value = CDate(EndDate)
```

`SerialNumber` is obtained through my for loop

```vb
For i = 3 To lrow3
    MachineSerial = Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("C" & i).Value
Next i
```

I also got some checks on my code to make sure that both dates exist and that `StartDate` is smaller than `EndDate`.

Note: when the month is selected, it appears as January, February, etc. so that the code doesn't think it is a USA format and it knows that the second value is the month.

Comment: I'd first replicate this in formula fashion `=COUNTIFS(....)` on that sheet. Once you get the `COUNTIFS` form working, then translate to code. Nothing appears incorrect in your current code.

Comment: @BigBen I have included an example of what my formula would look like, and it works completely fine as a formula, not sure of what is wrong with the code version.

Comment: Next guess would be the dates. Try using just the `MachineSerial` and `>=1` criteria for the moment - is the result greater than 0?

Comment: @BigBen I have tried the following, and it doesn't even print a result when I try this Worksheets("AnalysisMachine").Range("E" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("MachineData").Range("A:A"), Worksheets("MachineData").Range("L:L"), ">=1")

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` previously in your code?

Comment: @BigBen No On Error Resume Next

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` and inspect the Immediate Window output, instead of writing to a worksheet. Idk why you're not getting any output, but should be easier to use `Debug.Print`.

Comment: @BigBen I tried Debug.Print and it shows "True" for all values in the immediate window (for both my original formula and the one where I remove the dates)

Comment: @BigBen when I look at only SerialNumber it works fine, when I add the dates it gives me 0 each time (StartDate is lower than EndDate so that should be fine), but then if I look at SerialNumber and the ">=1" on their own it doesn't display anything at all, the cell is blank.

Comment: Why don't you share the rest of the relevant code? We don't know what's in `MachineSerial`, `StartDate`, and `EndDate`. BTW, replace `"<=" & CDate(EndDate) + 0.999988` with `"<" & CDate(EndDate) + 1`. Also, add a screenshot of your data.

Comment: @VBasic2008 MachineSerial is correct because I tested it on its own and it works fine. StartDate is 24/January/2023 and EndDate is 26/February/2023 and there is definitely data there for that timeframe.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've added more information about my code to the description of this question.

Comment: Use `DateSerial` to construct the date from parts. Or maybe `DateValue`. Your current approach looks suspect.

Comment: @BigBen I changed it so I use DateSerial but it still gives me 0 as a result for all of the CountIfs

Comment: What does `Debug.Print MachineSerial, CDate(StartDate), CDate(EndDate)` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen 24/01/2023 and 26/02/2023

Comment: @BigBen I added dim StartDate as Date and dim EndDate as Date but it still counts 0

Comment: @BigBen It works now, I have changed CDate to Cdbl and that did the trick.

Comment: @VBasic2008 it works now, I used DateSerial to generate the dates and changed CDate to Cdbl on my Countifs formulas and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating the dates as

```
StartDate = StartDay & "/" & StartMonth & "/" & StartYear
```

I changed it to be

```
Dim StartDate As Date
StartDate = DateSerial(StartYear, StartMonth, StartDay)
```

and then on the COUNTIFS part of the code I changed the cDate to be CDbl